# Dobbelt opin flow with DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, cloudpage

Im trying to make a dobbelt opt in flow, with the use of data extensions.. My idea is from API to call a trigger send, that send the mail out, and then somehow check if the user have clicked on the "confirm permission" button in the mail. My idea was to make an automation with SQL selection people from the _Click who have click on the link.. 
Any idea how I can do this with out all the sql automation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CloudPage with [RedirectTo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirectto.htm) function, as a URL in your Double Optin CTA.

Hence CloudPage will update subscriber data (confirm Double opt in) using AMPScript, and you can point to the external landing page in the RedirectTo call. Subscribers will not notice the CloudPage, as the redirect happens within backend.

Comment: Du er velkommen, Rasmus! Remember to mark the answer as accepted :-)

Answer (score 1):

On your CTA link in the email which you are asking the customer to confirm, you can point to a CloudPage.

From within the CloudPage which will confirm the customers action, use AMPScript to write / update a data extension.

If you have Journey Builder, you could also use that to make an decision on Click Activity and then use the Update Contact activity to update the data extension.

Comment: We are linking to an external page, so no cloud page.

Comment: But we do have journey builder.. but isn't the Activity step only after a certain amount of time? So e.g. Sent mail, wait 1 day, see if they have clicked.. but what if they click after 2 hours?

Comment: If not using Cloud Pages, then you could do it via API to update the data extension. For journey builder, correct - you can only make a decision after a period of time. Is there a reason why you don't want to do it by SQL? With SQL you could do it hourly automation. If you are wanting real time then do an API